# How i can pass new Object between Zuul filters, using spring context?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Currently, I have `AuthFilter` and here I received an `UserState`. I need to pass it to the next Filter. But how to do it right? Or exists other practices to resolve it?

```
public class AuthFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return PRE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER - 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        String requestURI = context.getRequest().getRequestURI();
        for (String authPath : authPaths) {
            if (requestURI.contains(authPath)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException {

        try {
            UserState userState = authService.getUserData();

            DefaultListableBeanFactory context = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();

            GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
            beanDefinition.setBeanClass(UserState.class);
            beanDefinition.setPropertyValues(new MutablePropertyValues() {
                {
                    add("user", userState);
                }
            });
            context.registerBeanDefinition("userState", beanDefinition);
        } catch (UndeclaredThrowableException e) {
            if (e.getUndeclaredThrowable().getClass() == UnauthorizedException.class) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException(e.getMessage());
            }

            if (e.getUndeclaredThrowable().getClass() == ForbiddenException.class) {
                throw new ForbiddenException(e.getMessage(), "The user is not allowed to make this request");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The zuul `RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();` is how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty sure filters are chained together and the request/response are passed through them.  You can add the data to the request, and have the next filter look for it.